# What could be making my truck skip?

Tags: chevrolet, rough-idle, silverado

I have a 2006 Chevy Silverado 1500. It's been skipping for several weeks now but not really throwing a code. I've changed the fuel pump and spark plugs but still skipped. Then I came out one day and it wouldn't start and the battery died while turning over trying to crank. I hooked my battery to another vehicle and jumped it off. The skipping seemed to stop while the jumper cables were on but as soon as they were taken off it started skipping once given gas in park so I got a new battery and alternator but still no luck. Now it'll stop skipping for several hours or even days then all of a sudden start back. I've waited until it was dark and looked for sparks to suggest a grounded wire but with no luck.

Now after the holidays and being off work any time my truck has sat over 12 hours it acts like it doesn't want to crank. It has good fuel pressure, also most of the skipping is when the truck is about to shift into second or third gear. Like I said also skips/misses in park.

I'm out of ideas. What does it sound like the issue most likely is?

Comment: Welcome to the site. How many miles on your truck? How do you know you have good fuel pressure? Have you actually put a fuel gauge on the rail and checked it? You say it's "not really throwing a code" ... not really implies it has thrown codes, but not all the time. If so, what are the codes?

Comment: Just to be sure ... when you say "skipping" do you mean the engine is missing? As in sounds like you have a dead cylinder at times (not all cylinders are firing all the time)?

Comment: What engine is in the truck?

Comment: The code it's throwing is an oxygen related one best I can tell and it's been giving it for over two years now and run fine up until recently. Yes I put a gauge on the fuel pressure and yes I mean missing. And it has the 4.3 liter v6

Comment: Also it doesn't have coil packs but an electronic distributor if that helps any